# Move child ul out of navigation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

**Example html:**

```
<ul class="navigation">

  <li class="home">Home</li>
  <li class="contact">Contact</li>

  <li class="service">Services
   <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li>All Services</li>
     <li>Cleaning</li>
     <li>Repair</li>
   </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="quote">Quote</li>
  <li class="social">Social</li>

</ul>
```

**Question:** How do I move `<ul class="sub-menu">` and all its children outside of the `<ul class="navigation">` using jQuery?

**For example like:**

```
<ul class="navigation">

  <li class="home">Home</li>
  <li class="contact">Contact</li>

  <li class="service">Services</li>

  <li class="quote">Quote</li>
  <li class="social">Social</li>

</ul>
<ul class="sub-menu">
     <li>All Services</li>
     <li>Cleaning</li>
     <li>Repair</li>
</ul>
```

This is for a wordpress install with a very odd menu setup. **I tried:**

```
(function($){
$( ".service .submenu" ).appendTo( ".navigation" );
})(jQuery);
```

Which I thought should work but didnt do anything.

**I also tried:**

```
(function($){
$( ".service .submenu" ).insertAfter( ".navigation" );
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$('.sub-menu').insertAfter('.navigation')` should work as well as your `$( ".service .submenu" ).insertAfter( ".navigation" );` is there an error?

Comment: No errors in the console. Its wordpress though so maybe its just a jerk lol...

Comment: If `.insertAfter` isn't working, you could try removing then re-appending the DOM element you want to move.

Comment: And where have you tried it? I suggest you look [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/) for a plugin that allows custom CSS/JS in WP.

Comment: `sub-menu` not `submenu`

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendTo` the **parent element** then it will work.

```js
(function($){
$(".service .sub-menu").appendTo("#parent");
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <ul class="navigation">

    <li class="home">Home</li>
    <li class="contact">Contact</li>

    <li class="service">Services
     <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li>All Services</li>
       <li>Cleaning</li>
       <li>Repair</li>
     </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="quote">Quote</li>
    <li class="social">Social</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($){

    var childmenu = $(".service .sub-menu").html();
    $('#navigation').append(childmenu);
    $(".service .sub-menu").remove();

})(jQuery);
```